# verifying firebase token on backend server

Tags: php, firebase-authentication

so im trying to use firebase auth to authenticate a user then once the user is registered I want to send the token to the backend server so i can verify the token and save the data onto my db , but my main issue is every time I register the user everything works well till I try to send the token to the backend , I'm not sure if the token actually gets sent to the backend because every time i try to check if it was sent nothing shows on my server , How could i possibly fix this :

so below is the code for sending the header to the backend server -

```
 Future authUser() async {
    try {
      final token = await _auth.currentUser!.getIdToken();
      print(token);
      final res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(API.register),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: token,
        },
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Data sent successfully!');
        print(res.body);
      } else {
        print('Data not sent!');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return "error";
    }
  }
```

then this is my code for server :

```
<?php
include('db_connection.php');

include('firebase.php');

use Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\FailedToVerifyToken;

//$idTokenString = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORISATION'];

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORISATION']))
{

    $idTokenString = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORISATION'];
    echo $idTokenString;

}else return;

try {
    $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($idTokenString);
} catch (FailedToVerifyToken $e) {
    echo 'The token is invalid: '.$e->getMessage();
}

$uid = $verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('sub');

$user = $auth->getUser($uid);
echo $user;
```